# Spark 1.6: filtering DataFrames generated by describe()

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

The problem arises when I call `describe` function on a DataFrame:

```scala
val statsDF = myDataFrame.describe()
```

Calling describe function yields the following output:

```
statsDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [summary: string, count: string]
```

I can show `statsDF` normally by calling `statsDF.show()`

```
+-------+------------------+
|summary|             count|
+-------+------------------+
|  count|             53173|
|   mean|104.76128862392568|
| stddev|3577.8184333911513|
|    min|                 1|
|    max|            558407|
+-------+------------------+
```

I would like now to get the standard deviation and the mean from `statsDF`, but when I am trying to collect the values by doing something like:

```scala
val temp = statsDF.where($"summary" === "stddev").collect()
```

I am getting `Task not serializable` exception.

I am also facing the same exception when I call:

```scala
statsDF.where($"summary" === "stddev").show()
```

It looks like we cannot filter DataFrames generated by `describe()` function?

Comment: I'm voting this up. It's weird now to be able to filter on the DF created by describe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have considered a toy dataset I had containing some health disease data

```
val stddev_tobacco = rawData.describe().rdd.map{ 
    case r : Row => (r.getAs[String]("summary"),r.get(1))
}.filter(_._1 == "stddev").map(_._2).collect
```

Comment: @Rami This should do the job, thought it's a bit silly and naïve... Tell me if this works for you !

Comment: Thanks @eliasah, it is strange that we can't filter theses DF. I will consider maybe to point this problem out to Spark guys.

Comment: @zero323 what do you think about this issue ? Should we open a issue on JIRA about it ?

Comment: @Rami it is actually strange to me ! That's why I'm asking the big chef about it :)

Comment: The big chef is great ;)

Comment: This is helpful. Can you suggest what modification is required to make this work for the entire row (when I have multiple numeric columns in original dataset)

Answer (score 2):

You can select from the dataframe:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import mean, min, max
df.select([mean('uniform'), min('uniform'), max('uniform')]).show()
+------------------+-------------------+------------------+
|      AVG(uniform)|       MIN(uniform)|      MAX(uniform)|
+------------------+-------------------+------------------+
|0.5215336029384192|0.19657711634539565|0.9970412477032209|
+------------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

You can also register it as a table and query the table:

```
val t = x.describe()
t.registerTempTable("dt")

%sql 
select * from dt
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use `selectExpr()` which also runs optimized, e.g. to obtain the min:

```
myDataFrame.selectExpr('MIN(count)').head()[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myDataFrame.describe().filter($"summary"==="stddev").show()
```

This worked quite nicely on Spark 2.3.0

Comment: Worked on Spark 2.1.0 as well