# Getting a value from DataFrame based on other column value (PySpark)

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe which I want to get the statistics

```
stats_df = df.describe(['mycol'])
stats_df.show()
```

```
+-------+------------------+
|summary|             mycol|
+-------+------------------+
|  count|               300|
|   mean|              2243|
| stddev|  319.419860456123|
|    min|              1400|
|    max|              3100|
+-------+------------------+
```

How do I extract the values of `min` and `max` in `mycol` using the `summary` `min` `max` column values? How do I do it by number index?

Comment: I've already answered this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35272086/spark-1-6-filtering-dataframes-generated-by-describe)

Comment: @eliasah Can please provide a Python version solution here? I have difficulty translating your solution, as I don't know Scala.

Comment: Ok I've written an answer below ! If it solves your problem, please accept and upvote :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok let's consider the following example :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import rand, randn
df = sqlContext.range(1, 1000).toDF('mycol')
df.describe().show()
# +-------+-----------------+
# |summary|            mycol|
# +-------+-----------------+
# |  count|              999|
# |   mean|            500.0|
# | stddev|288.5307609250702|
# |    min|                1|
# |    max|              999|
# +-------+-----------------+
```

If you want to access the row concerning stddev, per example, you'll just need to convert it into an RDD, collect it and convert it into a dictionary as following :

```
stats = dict(df.describe().map(lambda r : (r.summary,r.mycol)).collect())
print(stats['stddev'])
# 288.5307609250702
```

Comment: Useful map but you'll need to convert the describe dataframe to rdd: dict(df.describe().rdd.map(lambda r: (r.summary, r.High)).collect())

Answer (score 3):

You could easily assign a variable from a select on that dataframe.

```
x = stats_df.select('mycol').where('summary' == 'min')
```